# HC-05 module to Processing

Tags: bluetooth

I've been trying to make an application with arduino and HC-05 bluetooth module that sends information to processing.

In processing code, to read serial data I chose port with Serial.list()[x], where x is a number of opened port.
But each time I connect to HC-05 it connects for few seconds and disconnects - moreover there is a bug that when I click HC-05 in bluetooth menu at the top right corner to connect it adds another icon of this module to menu and one is connected(for these few seconds) and the other returns information that it cannot establish connection.

How to establish bluetooth connection HC-05 -- Processing?

I've googled it and usually it is sth with rfcomm.conf, but I can't see anything like that in my files.
I know that on windows there's similar situation (that HC-05 disconnects after few seconds), but it connects after running processing code. However, it does not work on elementary.

I'd be grateful for any help. :)